# Oracle query for grouping

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement for fetching records from a group which met some condition.Please find my input set of records below

```
ID  FIRSTNAME   SURNAME
123 E          Mcilwham
123 Emma       Mcilwham
123 Enda       Mcilwham
321 Lion       Mark
321 Lous       Mark
342 L          Isaac
342 L          Isaac
455 Lewis      hoting
455 L          hoting
325 D          Mark
```

In this record I need to do a group by based on ID and Surname.I need output in such a way that, for the same ID there should be at least one record whose length is 1 and for the same ID there should be other records whose length is greater that 1 and those record should start with the same letter as of the record whose length is 1.

In the above example ID:- 123,455 will cover the above said scenario.

Also I am not expecting any record in output where there is only record for that ID.(ID:- 325).

With the case of ID 342, this shouldn't come in the output as there are no records for this ID whose length is greater than 1.

Hope this is clear to every one. Please feel free to ask me if require more clarifications on this

Please find the query which I have used below, which is not giving me proper result as expected.

```
SELECT 
  C.ID,
  C.FIRST_NAME,
  C.SURNAME
  FROM TABLE1 C
WHERE C.ID IN
  (SELECT DISTINCT A.ID
  FROM TABLE1 A ,
    TABLE1 B
  WHERE A.ID                 = B.ID
  AND LENGTH(TRIM(A.FIRST_NAME))    <> LENGTH(TRIM(B.FIRST_NAME))
--  AND LENGTH(TRIM(B.FIRST_NAME))    <> LENGTH(TRIM(A.FIRST_NAME))
AND LENGTH(TRIM(A.FIRST_NAME))   = 1 OR  LENGTH(TRIM(B.FIRST_NAME)) = 1
  AND SUBSTR(TRIM(A.FIRST_NAME),1,1) = SUBSTR(TRIM(B.FIRST_NAME),1,1)
  --AND SUBSTR(TRIM(B.FIRST_NAME),1,1) = SUBSTR(TRIM(A.FIRST_NAME),1,1)
  AND TRIM(A.SURNAME) = TRIM(B.SURNAME)
  )
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Stack Overflow is not a writing code service, if you want someone to wirte code for you then hire a professional programmer.

Comment: Sorry for not giving the query which I have tried.Please find the code below

Comment: SELECT 
  C.ID,
  C.FIRST_NAME,
  C.SURNAME
  
FROM TABLE1 C
WHERE C.ID IN
  (SELECT DISTINCT A.ID
  FROM TABLE1 A ,
    TABLE1 B
  WHERE A.ID                 = B.ID
  AND LENGTH(TRIM(A.FIRST_NAME))    <> LENGTH(TRIM(B.FIRST_NAME))
--  AND LENGTH(TRIM(B.FIRST_NAME))    <> LENGTH(TRIM(A.FIRST_NAME))
AND LENGTH(TRIM(A.FIRST_NAME))   = 1 OR  LENGTH(TRIM(B.FIRST_NAME)) = 1
  AND SUBSTR(TRIM(A.FIRST_NAME),1,1) = SUBSTR(TRIM(B.FIRST_NAME),1,1)
  --AND SUBSTR(TRIM(B.FIRST_NAME),1,1) = SUBSTR(TRIM(A.FIRST_NAME),1,1)
  AND TRIM(A.SURNAME) = TRIM(B.SURNAME)
  )
ORDER BY 1

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation over ID and surname:

```
select
  id,
  firstname,
  surname
from
(
  select
    id, 
    firstname, 
    surname, 
    min(length(firstname)) over (partition by id, surname) as min_length,
    max(length(firstname)) over (partition by id, surname) as max_length,
    count(distinct substr(firstname, 1, 1)) 
                           over (partition by id, surname) as count_distinct_initials
  from table1
)
where min_length = 1
  and max_length > 1
  and count_distinct_initials = 1
order by id, surname, firstname;
```

Comment: This query is working perfectly except for one scenario for the ID NO 342

Comment: @GIN: Why do you think so? 342 shall be excluded from the results. The condition `and max_length > 1` does exactly this, because the maximum length is 1.

Comment: Ok thanks Thorsten. The issue was with data, because of a leading space

Answer (score 0):

The following query satisfies all requirements that you specified for your specific data set. Depending on the actual data that you have to work with, you may need to be more specific.

```
with sample_data as(
   select 123 as id, 'E'     as firstname, 'Mcilwham' as surname from dual union all
   select 123 as id, 'Emma'  as firstname, 'Mcilwham' as surname from dual union all
   select 123 as id, 'Enda'  as firstname, 'Mcilwham' as surname from dual union all
   select 321 as id, 'Lion'  as firstname, 'Mark'     as surname from dual union all
   select 321 as id, 'Lous'  as firstname, 'Mark'     as surname from dual union all
   select 342 as id, 'L'     as firstname, 'Isaac'    as surname from dual union all
   select 342 as id, 'L'     as firstname, 'Isaac'    as surname from dual union all
   select 455 as id, 'Lewis' as firstname, 'hoting'   as surname from dual union all
   select 455 as id, 'L'     as firstname, 'hoting'   as surname from dual union all
   select 325 as id, 'D'     as firstname, 'Mark'     as surname from dual
)
select id
      ,surname
      ,listagg(firstname, ',') within group (order by firstname) as firstnames
      ,count(*) as nof_firstnames 
  from sample_data a
 group 
    by id
      ,surname      
having count(*) > 1                 -- at least one record 
   and min(length(firstname)) = 1   -- at least one record has length = 1
   and max(length(firstname)) > 1   -- at least one record has a length greater than 1
```

> In this record I need to do a group by based on ID and Surname.I need
>   output in such a way that, for the same ID there should be at least
>   one record whose length is 1 and for the same ID there should be other
>   records whose length is greater that 1 and those record should start
>   with the same letter as of the record whose length is 1.

What would happen when there are multiple records for length = 1 and length > 1?For example Alexander does not start with 'R'. Bengt does not start with 'A' but there is a record 'B'. Cedric starts with 'C' but it doesn't match the 'A' record.

```
ID  FIRSTNAME   SURNAME
1   R           Bahlsten
1   Ronnie      Bahlsten
1   Alexander   Bahlsten
2   A           Andersson
2   Anna        Andersson
2   B           Andersson
2   Bengt       Andersson
3   C           Diggory
3   A           Diggory
3   Cedric      Diggory
```

Comment: In this case also that record should come.

Comment: Can you specify your output requirements? Do you want to return all the names in the group (id, surname) or only the firstnames within that group that satisfies the other requirements?

Comment: For example, do you want both Emma and Enda?